# SQL join Fill in nulls with prior value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have two tables

**Table A**

| Time | ColA |
| --- | --- |
| 2pm | 3 |
| 3pm | 4 |
| 4pm | 4 |

**Table B**

| Time | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| 2pm | 13 |
| 4pm | 27 |

Can I write a query join that will fill the 3pm value for col B with either the 2pm or 4pm values?  The result could be:

**Result Table**

| Time | ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2pm | 3 | 13 |
| 3pm | 4 | 13 |
| 4pm | 4 | 27 |

Comment: Use JOIN on Time

Comment: I think you should give a better example than this - if it's a real-world situation that you're trying to deal with, showing some more sample data would probably be good.  Also, StackOverflow is more about helping you to overcome issues with your own code, so providing examples of what you've already attempted would also be good.  (However, as a quick example, I'm guessing that you source tables will actually probably contain many rows each - what is the relationship between the two tables?  Simply joining all records, with no specific relationship, will give you a very large dataset)

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't know how many missing values you might have, I would not suggest using `lag()`.  One method is `outer apply`:

```
select a.*, b.colB
from a outer apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from b
      where b.time <= a.time
      order by b.time desc
     ) b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FULL JOIN` with `LAG`

```
SELECT Time, ColA, 
       CASE WHEN ColB IS NULL THEN Lag([ColB], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [Time]) 
       ELSE ColB 
       END ColB 
FROM Table1 A FULL JOIN Table2 B ON A.Time = B.Time
```

Comment: Thank you Vignesh that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Temporal12. . . This does not work if you have two missing values in a row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I agree